# Add PHP version to lampp

Tags: php, lampp

i have a lampp stack on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. It was installed from an apachefriends.org installer ages ago. As i can see in the binaries it has 2 `PHP` versions already installed with just a symlink for the actual `php`. Now i want to add a new `PHP` version (and keep the ones installed), in this case some 7.x on top of 5.x that are already present.

I think i could download and build/configure PHP but actually i have no idea how it would integrate into lampp with the existing versions. Particularly extensions, and possibly different config files. Would they use the same? Is it possible anyway?

Comment: maybe this question would be more at home at https://askubuntu.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, follow:

Add PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get upgrade;
```

**Install Apache & MySQL** (if not already installed):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php-gettext php-xdebug;
```

**Install PHP5.6** (if not already installed):

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-mysql php5.6-mbstring libapache2-mod-php5.6;
```

**Install PHP7.1** (if not already installed):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring libapache2-mod-php7.1;
```

> **Switching between PHP versions** (via commands [`a2enmod` & `a2dismod`](http://man.he.net/man8/a2enmod)):

**Switch PHP Versions (7.1->5.6)**:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1; sudo a2enmod php5.6; sudo service apache2 restart;
```

**Switch PHP Versions (5.6->7.1)**:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1; sudo a2dismod php5.6; sudo service apache2 restart;
```

Comment: apt update and upgrade should be in switched order: first update (updates the package list), then upgrade (installes new or updated packages)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i know this. The question was meant differently because it would mean reinstalling lampp manually not integrating into an existing configuration (porting all of it would probably be a huge effort) - which is not installed from the repos, nor does the installed apache come with a2(en/dis)mod or thelike. Question was more if i could somehow get another php-binary that is usable by the old apache instance probably in the same (symlink) way